# Print a part of stream-string?

Tags: python, string, printing, stream

How can I print what's after a colon like 's':, 'E':, or 'p': by giving the symbol as reference? I tried this based on all what I know so far but I get a weird error:

```
        XXXX = f"{{'stream': 'ABCDEF', 'data': {{'s': 'ABC', 'E': 1123, 'p': '0.0',  'q': '0.0'}}}}"
        print(XXXX)
        print(XXXX['data']['p'])
```

Output:

```
{'stream': 'ABCDEF', 'data': {'s': 'ABC', 'E': 1123, 'p': '0.0',  'q': '0.0'}}
Error: in main: print(XXXX['data']['p'])
       TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `ast` module, you can simply do what you need:

```py
import ast
XXXX = f"{{'stream': 'ABCDEF', 'data': {{'s': 'ABC', 'E': 1123, 'p': '0.0',  'q': '0.0'}}}}"
myDict = ast.literal_eval(XXXX)
print(myDict["data"]["p"])
```

##### Output

```
'0.0'
```

Comment: Is the problem because it is not a dictionary?

Comment: @nolimits You are absolutely right. `XXXX` variable in your question was a string.

Comment: Haha! Learned something today :) Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

Since XXXX is a string and the example you provided is a json that you want to convert i would sugest the following:

```
import json

#replace the single quote for double quote in order to parse the json string
x = json.loads(XXXX.replace("'", '"'))

#print the dictionary key you wanted
print(x['data']['p'])
```

This works as expected for the given input. If you have any other samples that differ from the one provided please let me know.